# Creating a DbContext without connecting to a database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dbcontext

Is there a way to create a DbContext without actually connecting to a database?

I want to be able to access the CSDL and SSDL metadata, like so:

```
var objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)myDbContext).ObjectContext;
var ssdl = objContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetItemCollection(DataSpace.SSpace);
var csdl = objContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetItemCollection(DataSpace.CSpace);
```

but I don't want to access the database at all. Ideally, I'd want to be able to access SSDL/CSDL metadata without even having a database.

Comment: You can when you have an EDMX file, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/36357185/1860652 - not sure about code-first

Comment: If I had the EDMX file, I could just read CSDL/SSDL from there, without having a DbContext. Interesting link though, so thanks.

Comment: Check the whole answer - you can create an EDMX in memory using EdmxWriter then process that. It does take a while but it's doable!

Answer (score 1):

The dbContext is an abstraction over the database . If there is no database , then there is no abstraction . of cource you can create a DbContext without connecting to a database.
If you set the database initializer to null for your context then Code First will never attempt to create a database for you:

```
DbDatabase.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
```

But it is not useful in your case

Comment: Is there any way to just get the metadata without a DbContext/ObjectContext and a database?

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36357185/1860652) to a similar question (simplified code below) - this works for Code First only (the EDMX version is in the linked answer). The key is to create the context using the "App=EntityFramework" connection string.

```
public static MetadataWorkspace GetMetadataWorkspaceFromCodeFirst<TContext>(Func<string, TContext> createFromConnectionString) where TContext : DbContext
{
    using (var ctx = createFromConnectionString("App=EntityFramework"))
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(ctx, writer);
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var xDoc = XDocument.Load(ms);
        var runtime = xDoc.Root.Elements().First(c => c.Name.LocalName == "Runtime");
        var cSpaceLoader = new EdmItemCollection(GetXmlReader(runtime, "ConceptualModels"));
        var sSpaceLoader = new StoreItemCollection(GetXmlReader(runtime, "StorageModels"));
        var mSpaceLoader = new StorageMappingItemCollection(cSpaceLoader, sSpaceLoader,
            GetXmlReader(runtime, "Mappings"));
        return new MetadataWorkspace(() => cSpaceLoader, () => sSpaceLoader, () => mSpaceLoader);
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<XmlReader> GetXmlReader(XContainer runtimeElement, string elementName)
{
    var model = runtimeElement.Elements().First(c => c.Name.LocalName == elementName).Elements().First();
    yield return XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(model.ToString()));
}
```

Requires that your `DbContext` has a constructor with one `string` parameter which you pass as a delegate into the call

Answer (score 0):

In case someone was looking for a way to create `dbContext` without connecting to the database just for accessing metadata: you can create static readonly field and initialize `dbContext` with inmemory provider, like this:

```
public static readonly AppDbContext DbContextForMetadata = new BillingDbContext(new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext>()
              .UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
              .Options);
```

And use this all over your application for accessing metadata wherever you need.