# Is it possible to retrieve a MetadataWorkspace without having a connection to a database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am writing a test library that needs to traverse the Entity Framework `MetadataWorkspace` for a given `DbContext` type. However, as this is a test library I would rather not have a connection to the database - it introduces dependencies that may not be available from the test environment.

When I try to get a reference to the `MetadataWorkspace` like so:

```
var metadata = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;
```

I get a `SqlException`:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Is it possible to do what I want without a connection string?

Comment: How do you instantiate `context`?

Comment: @GertArnold I'm just using a parameterless constructor

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes you can do this by feeding context a dummy connection string. Note that usually when you call parameterless constructor of DbContext, it will look for connection string with the name of your context class in app.config file of main application. If that is the case and you cannot change this behavior (like you don't own the source code of context in question) - you will have to update app.config with that dummy conneciton string (can be done in runtime too). If you can call DbContext constructor with connection string, then:

```
var cs = String.Format("metadata=res://*/{0}.csdl|res://*/{0}.ssdl|res://*/{0}.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=\"\"", "TestModel");
using (var ctx = new TestDBEntities(cs)) {
    var metadata = ((IObjectContextAdapter)ctx).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;
    // no throw here
    Console.WriteLine(metadata);                
}
```

So you providing only parameters important to obtain metadata workspace, and providing empty connection string.

UPDATE: after more thought, you don't need to use such hacks and instantiate context at all.

```
public static MetadataWorkspace GetMetadataWorkspaceOf<T>(string modelName) where T:DbContext {
    return new MetadataWorkspace(new[] { $"res://*/{modelName}.csdl", $"res://*/{modelName}.ssdl", $"res://*/{modelName}.msl" }, new[] {typeof(T).Assembly});
}
```

Here you just use constructor of MetadataWorkspace class directly, passing it paths to target metadata elements and also assembly  to inspect. Note that this method makes some assumptions: that metadata artifacts are embedded into resources (usually they are, but can be external, or embedded under another paths) and that everything needed is in the same assembly as Context class itself (you might in theory have context in one assembly and entity classes in another, or something). But I hope you get the idea.

UPDATE2: to get metadata workspace of code-first model is somewhat more complicated, because edmx file for that model is generated at runtime. Where and how it is generated is implementation detail. However, you can still get metadata workspace with some efforts:

```
    public static MetadataWorkspace GetMetadataWorkspaceOfCodeFirst<T>() where T : DbContext {
        // require constructor which accepts connection string
        var constructor = typeof (T).GetConstructor(new[] {typeof (string)});
        if (constructor == null)
            throw new Exception("Constructor with one string argument is required.");
        // pass dummy connection string to it. You cannot pass empty one, so use some parameters there
        var ctx = (DbContext) constructor.Invoke(new object[] {"App=EntityFramework"});
        try {                
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            var writer = new XmlTextWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8);
            // here is first catch - generate edmx file yourself and save to xml document
            EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(ctx, writer);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var rawEdmx = XDocument.Load(ms);
            // now we are crude-parsing edmx to get to the elements we need
            var runtime = rawEdmx.Root.Elements().First(c => c.Name.LocalName == "Runtime");                
            var cModel = runtime.Elements().First(c => c.Name.LocalName == "ConceptualModels").Elements().First();
            var sModel = runtime.Elements().First(c => c.Name.LocalName == "StorageModels").Elements().First();
            var mModel = runtime.Elements().First(c => c.Name.LocalName == "Mappings").Elements().First();

            // now we build a list of stuff needed for constructor of MetadataWorkspace
            var cItems = new EdmItemCollection(new[] {XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(cModel.ToString()))});
            var sItems = new StoreItemCollection(new[] {XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(sModel.ToString()))});
            var mItems = new StorageMappingItemCollection(cItems, sItems, new[] {XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(mModel.ToString()))});
            // and done
            return new MetadataWorkspace(() => cItems, () => sItems, () => mItems);
        }
        finally {
            ctx.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This looks promising but I get a MetadataException: "Unable to load the specified metadata resource." - full stack trace [here](http://pastebin.com/raw/4kdNqCmk). Any ideas?

Comment: Using which of the above methods?

Comment: Sorry - that's using either method. EF6 Database-First if that helps

Comment: Yes I tested this on EF6 Database First model, so should work. Are you sure you set correct model name? This is usually the name of your edmx file (I mean second method, it seems more reliable).

Comment: Aha! I was missing the namespace. Brilliant, both methods work! That's fantastic, thank you

Comment: I will award the bounty when I'm allowed to - thanks for your help

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: I haven't been able to get either approach to work without an EDMX file present (ie in a Code First scenario). Do you know if it's possible?

Comment: Fantastic! Where did you learn this, if you don't mind me asking? My googling has been pretty futile when it comes to the MetadataWorkspace

Comment: Nowhere, basically by exploring what MetadataWorkspace constructor accepts :) But in many cases decompiler helps to check how library author does that. I use JetBrains decompiler, it's free and can be integrated in Visual Studio. So that when you do Go To Definition - it decompiles code on the fly, making it easy to inspect external sources.

Comment: Just wanted to add that in order to be able to resolve entity types into clr types with code first (GetMetadataWorkspaceOfCodeFirst), you need to call the LoadFromAssembly method on the MetadataWorkspace before returning it. LoadFromAssembly can be called with typeof(T).Assembly if all of your entities (and their base types besides object) are in the same assembly as the DbContext.

Answer (score 3):

The solution proposed by Evk did not work for me as `EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx` would eventually connect to the database.

Here is how I solved this:

```
var dbContextType = typeof(MyDbContext);
var dbContextInfo = new DbContextInfo(dbContextType, new DbProviderInfo(providerInvariantName: "System.Data.SqlClient", providerManifestToken: "2008"));
using (var context = dbContextInfo.CreateInstance() ?? throw new Exception($"Failed to create an instance of {dbContextType}. Does it have a default constructor?"))
{
    var workspace = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;
    // ... use the workspace ...
}
```

By creating the context this way, Entity Framework does not try to connect to the database when accessing the `ObjectContext` property.

Note that your `DbContext` class must have a default constructor for this solution to work.

Comment: This is helpful but did not help in my case as our template-generated context did contain a default constructor which called the base with the connection string name. However, this helped me to understand how I could easily modify the template to support this approach.

Comment: I didn't check if it creates a connection as you say, but for me the call to `EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx` takes 30(!) full seconds in debug or test mode. With your solution it took 2 seconds to complete the test. Immense improvement, thank you. I'll have to do some more tests though, as it still seems too expensive for a foreign key lookup. Plus I too would have to mess with our context's default constructor and generating template like @dhochee